# Where is android SDK location?

Tags: android

Here's what I did

1. download android studio (android-studio-ide-135.1538390-windows.zip)
2. unzip it and move the android-studio folder to directory "c:\users\andy"
3. start up "studio.exe" in the bin directory
4. select Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure
5. what should I put in the Android SDK location field? Whatever directories I put in, it keeps saying invalid sdk path

Thanks,

- Java JDK: 1.6 update 45
- OS: Windows 7

Comment: I thought the sdk was included in the Android Studio.

Comment: That's the Java JDK, not the Android SDK.

Comment: not your JDK. you have to download android sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android Studio 0.8.14 (the now-current download), in addition to downloading Android Studio, you *also* need to *separately* [download the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), then tell Android Studio where you set up your Android SDK.

Comment: that's a bit weird. there is no indication of this requirement on the android studio download page.

Comment: Thanks.  The wordings are kind of misleading on the button to download the Android Studio. It said download the studio and SDK.  It's working for me now.

Comment: @njzk2: Yeah, I know. My understanding is that it is a temporary measure.