# Where does gradlew look for an Android SDK?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

How can I tell which Android SDK gradlew uses?  For example, when I run `./gradlew dist`, how can I tell where it's looking on my disk for an Android SDK?

A similar question was [Where is android SDK location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176674/where-is-android-sdk-location) but it's quite outdated and doesn't specifically ask about gradlew.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `./gradlew dist` looks for the Android SDK referenced in the local.properties `sdk.dir` parameter.

I tested this by changing the `sdk.dir` parameter to an invalid directory (`/Users/me/Library/Android/ZZZsdk`) and that gave me the following error when running `./gradlew dist`:

```
my-project[develop]08:48:11 ./gradlew dist

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/Users/me/Library/Android/ZZZsdk' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```